# How to access UIView from nib via restorationIdentifier?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

Within `SearchTokenViews.xib` I have three `UIViews`. I know that I can access that nib like this:

```
let searchTokenViewsNIB = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("SearchTokenViews", owner: self, options: nil)
```

and then:

```
let firstSearchToken = searchTokenViewsNIB.first as! SearchTokenView
let secondSearchToken = searchTokenViewsNIB[1] as! SearchTokenView
let thirdSearchToken = searchTokenViewsNIB.last as! SearchTokenView
```

But what determine the order of that three? Wouldn't it be better to access it via `restorationIdentifier` similar to view controllers?

```
let controller = UIStoryboard(name: "Settings", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("")
```

**How can I do the same with UIView and .xib file?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution I have found so far is:

```
extension NSBundle {

    func loadNibNamed(named: String, owner: AnyObject!, identifier: String) -> UIView? {
        return loadNibNamed(named, owner: owner, options: nil).filter({ $0.restorationIdentifier == identifier }).first as? UIView
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that loading them all and searching is the only way if the views are all in the same nib.

Answer (score 1):

Following the apple guide [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622494-restorationidentifier):

> This property indicates whether state information in the view should
>   be preserved; it is also used to identify the view during the
>   restoration process. The value of this property is nil by default,
>   which indicates that the view’s state does not need to be saved.
>   Assigning a string object to the property lets the owning view
>   controller know that the view has relevant state information to save
>
> Simply setting the value of this property is not enough to ensure that
>   the view is preserved and restored.

In conclusion, it's practically impossible to "instantiate" a new view by using only this property.